# Convert operator to string

Tags: syntax, formatting

How to programmatically convert an operator such as `Equilibrium` into its displayed form as a string? The conversion should work like this:

```
FullForm[convert /@ {Equilibrium, LongRightArrow, LeftVector, Equal}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried various methods with no avail:

- converting to strings and wrapping in `"\[...]"`
- using different form wrappers (`DisplayForm`, `TraditionalForm`, etc.)
- using low level boxes, but since that is really not my alley, I was a bit clueless
- since operators with built-in meaning are used too, argument usage does not seem viable (e.g. `ToString[Equal["", ""]]` which returns `True`)

Comment: Don't be confused by Mma interpretation of Unicode chars. Try **ToCharacterCode@ToString@Equilibrium["a", "a"]** and them **FromCharacterCode@% // FullForm**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to work

```
convert[str_] := Module[{stream, output},
  stream = StringToStream["\"\\[" <> ToString[str] <> "]\""];
  output = Read[stream];
  Close[stream];
  output]

convert /@ {Equilibrium, LongRightArrow, LeftVector, Equal} // InputForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

You could also do something like this:

```
convert[str_] := ToExpression["\"\\[" <> ToString[str] <> "]\""]

convert /@ {Equilibrium, LongRightArrow, LeftVector, Equal} // InputForm
```

Answer (score 10):

How about (**updated** based on TomD's comment):

```
convert = StringTrim@ToString[HoldForm@#["", " "]]&
```

then,

```
In[]:= convert/@{Equilibrium,LongRightArrow,LeftVector,Equilibrium}
Out[]= {\[Equilibrium],\[LongRightArrow],\[LeftVector],\[Equilibrium]}
```

Note, that the output here is a string:

```
In[]:= Head/@%
Out[]= {String,String,String,String}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit** Note, this also works on operators like `Plus` or `Minus`.

Comment: Nice solution, and almost perfect: the `Equal` sign (it is now correctly present in my original post) that is returned is the two-character format (`==`) instead of the one-character version (see my updated Q). This difference can be a probelem if you simplify the solution to this: `StringTake[ToString[HoldForm@str["", ""]], {2}]`, as it clips the `==` sign to `=`.

Comment: That's a good point. Let me see what I can figure out.

Comment: Nice solution. A slight modification with `StringTrim`. For example `StringTrim@ToString@HoldForm@#["", ""] & /@ {Equilibrium, 
  LongRightArrow, Equal, SameQ, Plus}`.

Comment: @TomD Good point. Forgot about that function. Still stuck on that double-equals, though. Seems like Heike's second solution might work better.